# Jenkins Pipeline: use Windows environment variable with '(' in it

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, special-characters

In my Jenkins pipeline I want to access the Windows environment variable named "ProgramFiles(x86)". However, I do not know what syntax I have to use to make Jenkins pipeline understand that the '(x86)' is part of the environment variable name. I keep getting an error with for example "echo env.ProgramFiles(x86)

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: x86 for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

I also tried

```
echo "${ProgramFiles(x86)}"
```

and

```
echo "${env.ProgramFiles(x86)}"
```

but no success there either.

Comment: Maybe try to escape as `\(` , but I am not sure if it will work, theoretically two backslashes will be needed (in case if they need to be escaped as well :D ) so then 
`\\(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use single quotes around the variable name see below example:

```
echo "${env.'ProgramFiles(x86)'}"
```

Comment: This is interesting. Is there any documentation around this, or is just inherited from Groovy?